# Is that sentence redundant?

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy

This question is my future research work

> How does modernization in the transport road network sector affect on economic development of Kazakhstan?

Does the question sound correct?

It seems to me. There is redundancy in usage of these words

> the transport road network sector

Comment: All roads are for transport, but not all transport is by road. The phrase you need is _road transport_ (as distinct from rail transport etc.). I would say that _network_ was unnecessary too.

Comment: And delete the **on**. Things have an **effect on** or they **affect something**, in this case **affect the economic development ......** (Either **affect economic development IN K...** or **affect THE economic development OF K...**

Comment: 'affect [something] ', not 'affect on [something]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Road network" means all of the physical roads themselves.

"Transport sector" means the industry that surrounds transport: freight, buses, taxis, trains, airports, road management, etc.

"Road transport sector" could mean the part of the transport sector that is just roads (ie, not trains, planes etc).

I don't know what you mean by combining all four words though.